# Can't connect to server after changing location / ip

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, putty, iptables

I am trying to connect to my debian server from my workplace. However, it always gives me a timeout in Putty / WinSCP on Port 22. I have tried accessing the server through the web via Xterm.js and NoVNC, which works perfectly. I also need to mention that connecting to the server works perfectly fine at home, it's just that in the workplace it doesn't work. I am able to ping the server from the cmd line in Windows though. I have reinstalled the server, still doesn't work. My Firewall can't be the problem, since I can connect to other servers via SSH in PuTTY and WinSCP without any problems. My iptables -L:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
f2b-sshd   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports ssh

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain f2b-sshd (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     all  --  49.88.112.113        anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  222.186.190.2        anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

My /etc/ssh/ssh_config:

```
# This is the ssh client system-wide configuration file.  See
# ssh_config(5) for more information.  This file provides defaults for
# users, and the values can be changed in per-user configuration files
# or on the command line.

# Configuration data is parsed as follows:
#  1. command line options
#  2. user-specific file
#  3. system-wide file
# Any configuration value is only changed the first time it is set.
# Thus, host-specific definitions should be at the beginning of the
# configuration file, and defaults at the end.

# Site-wide defaults for some commonly used options.  For a comprehensive
# list of available options, their meanings and defaults, please see the
# ssh_config(5) man page.

Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
#   ForwardX11 no
#   ForwardX11Trusted yes
#   PasswordAuthentication yes
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
#   GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#   GSSAPITrustDNS no
#   BatchMode no
#   CheckHostIP yes
#   AddressFamily any
#   ConnectTimeout 0
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
```